# Newline not appearing in sent sms

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am currently developing a web app using `PHP` and using `twilio`, to **SMS** from it.

The issue I am facing is that, after reading the documentation I began using `\n` in my **SMS** body, to insert a new line, but on the receiver end, never is the new line appearing. (Tests took place on an *Android 4.4.4* mobile)

Comment: If you are sending it in a context which requires URL encoding you should try `%0a`, see, https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-my-sms-message

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here. If you're sending a message with our PHP helper library we take care of [encoding the newline](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-my-sms-message) for you:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
  '+15555555555', // From a Twilio number in your account
  '+15555551234', // Text any number
  "Hello monkey!\n how are you?"
);
```

If you're sending a message by making an HTTP request to our API directly you'll need to make sure the information you're sending is URL encoded. Thankfully PHP makes it pretty easy with the `urlencode` function:

```
$params = 
        '&From=' . urlencode("+15555555555") . 
        '&To=' .  urlencode("+15555551234") . 
        '&Body=' . urlencode("Hello monkey!\n how are you?");
```

Hope that helps!